# How do I Record a console session?

Tags: video, console

I know how to get to the console on my computer by pressing `Ctrl` `Alt` `F1` - `F6`.

When I run a screen recording program and switch to console and then switch back by pressing `Ctrl` `Alt` `F7`, I save the video however the recording of the console didn't show up.

Is there a program that will let me do that.  Or a program that will simulate the console session in full screen so you don't see the GUI.

I am using xVidCap and it doesn't record the console.

Comment: what recording programs have you tried ?

Comment: I am using xVidCap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot record the ttys because they do not run on the X server. You will need to use Virtual box to run a virtual instance of Ubuntu and record the console using that. Virtualbox can run your virtual system fullscreen.

Comment: I don't have a very fast computer is there a text based version of ubuntu that I can install in virtual box

Comment: @wil yes, just use the minimal cd or the server edition :).